# Prompting the user to send an application request to a friend

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-as3-api

I have a facebook canvas app (flash). 
I have a user who is visiting the app. 
I have a button  that the user clicks for the purpose of inviting a friend to the app.

I understand that this can be done via the js sdk: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

However I am already using the facebook_as3_api, and I would prefer to avoid using multiple facebook api's.

Does the facebook_as3_api have a way of doing this, and if not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

http://facebook-actionscript-api.googlecode.com/svn/release/current/docs/index.html

Comment: as far as I can tell the facebook_as3_api (including the FacebookDesktop class) does not offer a straightforward invite-a-friend method ... I believe that inviting-a-friend would require some usage of FacebookDesktop.api( ??? ) method or something ... it can apparently be done using the javascript sdk via its request dialog.